# PySpark: Create a new column in dataframe based on another dataframe's cell values

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have PySpark dataframe `dhl_price` of the following form:

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+------+
|Weight|    A|    B|    C|     D|
+------+-----+-----+-----+------+
|     1|16.78|17.05|20.23|  40.1|
|     2|16.78|17.05|20.23| 58.07|
|     3|18.43|18.86| 25.0| 66.03|
|     4|20.08|20.67|29.77| 73.99|
```

So you can get the delivery price based on the category (i.e. the columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`) and the weight of your parcel (i.e. the first column `Weight`) and for weights larger than 30, we have prices specified only for 30, 40, 50 etc.

I also have PySpark dataframe `requests`, one row for each request by a customer. It includes columns `product_weight`, `Type` (the category that is in dhl_price). I want to create a new column in requests `delivery_fee` based on `dhl_price` dataframe. In particular, for each row in `dhl_price` column, I want to get a cell value in `dhl_price` where column is the one specified in column `Type` and row is the one specified in column `product_weight` of `requests` dataframe.

So far I could code it in **pandas**:

```
def get_dhl_fee(weight, type):
    if weight <= 30:
        price = dhl_price.loc[dhl_price["Weight"] == weight][type].values[0]
    else:
        price = dhl_price.loc[dhl_price["Weight"] >= weight].reset_index(drop = True).iloc[0][type].values[0]
    return price
    
new_requests["dhl_fee"] = new_requests.apply(lambda x: get_dhl_fee(x["product_weight_g"], x["Type"]), axis = 1)
```

How can I do the same with PySpark? I tried to use PySpark's UDF:

```
# Define the UDF (User-Defined Function) for calculating DHL fee
@fn.udf(returnType=DoubleType())
def get_dhl_fee(product_weight_g, calculate_way):
    broadcast_dhl_price = fn.broadcast(dhl_price)

    if weight <= 30:
        price = broadcast_dhl_price.filter(dhl_price["Weight"] == weight).select(calculate_way).first()[0]
    else:
        price = broadcast_dhl_price.filter(dhl_price["Weight"] >= weight).select(calculate_way).first()[0]

    return price

# Register the UDF
sc.udf.register("get_dhl_fee", get_dhl_fee)

# Apply the UDF to calculate dhl_fee column
requests = requests.withColumn("dhl_fee", get_dhl_fee(fn.col("product_weight"), fn.col("Type")))
```

but it returns error SPARK-5063:

> "It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a
> broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only
> be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
dhl_price.show()
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|Weight|    A|    B|    C|    D|
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     1|16.78|17.05|20.23| 40.1|
|     2|16.78|17.05|20.23|58.07|
|     3|18.43|18.86| 25.0|66.03|
|     4|20.08|20.67|29.77|73.99|
|    30|20.08|20.67|29.77|73.99|
|    40|21.08|21.67|30.77|74.99|
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+

requests.show()
+--------------+----+
|product_weight|type|
+--------------+----+
|             1|   B|
|             2|   D|
|             4|   A|
|            30|   A|
|           100|   C|
+--------------+----+
```

#### Code

Create a column of map type which maps type to corresponding price for a given weight

```
c = dhl_price.columns[1:]
dhl_price_map = dhl_price.select('Weight', F.map_from_arrays(F.array(*map(F.lit, c)), F.array(*c)).alias('price'))
dhl_price_map.show()


+------+--------------------+
|Weight|               price|
+------+--------------------+
|     1|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|
|     2|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|
|     3|{A -> 18.43, B ->...|
|     4|{A -> 20.08, B ->...|
|    30|{A -> 20.08, B ->...|
|    40|{A -> 21.08, B ->...|
+------+--------------------+
```

Assign a unique identifier for each row in the requests dataframe

```
df = requests.withColumn('id_', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show()
+--------------+----+-----------+
|product_weight|type|        id_|
+--------------+----+-----------+
|             1|   B| 8589934592|
|             2|   D|25769803776|
|             4|   A|34359738368|
|            30|   A|51539607552|
|           100|   C|60129542144|
+--------------+----+-----------+
```

Join the two dataframes on weight condition then use the indexing to yank the value of price corresponding to type for each row

```
df = df.join(dhl_price_map, on=df['product_weight'] >= dhl_price_map['Weight'], how='left')
df = df.withColumn('dhl_fee', F.expr("price[type]"))
df.show()


+--------------+----+-----------+------+--------------------+-------+
|product_weight|type|        id_|Weight|               price|dhl_fee|
+--------------+----+-----------+------+--------------------+-------+
|             1|   B| 8589934592|     1|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|  17.05|
|             2|   D|25769803776|     1|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|   40.1|
|             2|   D|25769803776|     2|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|  58.07|
|             4|   A|34359738368|     1|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|  16.78|
|             4|   A|34359738368|     2|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|  16.78|
|             4|   A|34359738368|     3|{A -> 18.43, B ->...|  18.43|
|             4|   A|34359738368|     4|{A -> 20.08, B ->...|  20.08|
|            30|   A|51539607552|     1|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|  16.78|
|            30|   A|51539607552|     2|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|  16.78|
|            30|   A|51539607552|     3|{A -> 18.43, B ->...|  18.43|
|            30|   A|51539607552|     4|{A -> 20.08, B ->...|  20.08|
|            30|   A|51539607552|    30|{A -> 20.08, B ->...|  20.08|
|           100|   C|60129542144|     1|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|  20.23|
|           100|   C|60129542144|     2|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|  20.23|
|           100|   C|60129542144|     3|{A -> 18.43, B ->...|   25.0|
|           100|   C|60129542144|     4|{A -> 20.08, B ->...|  29.77|
|           100|   C|60129542144|    30|{A -> 20.08, B ->...|  29.77|
|           100|   C|60129542144|    40|{A -> 21.08, B ->...|  30.77|
+--------------+----+-----------+------+--------------------+-------+
```

Create a window specification to rank the `Weight` per unique row in the requests, and then filter the rows to retain only those corresponding to the maximum weight in `dhl_price`.

```
W = Window.partitionBy('id_').orderBy(F.desc('Weight'))
df = df.withColumn('rank', F.dense_rank().over(W)).filter('rank == 1')

+--------------+----+-----------+------+--------------------+-------+----+
|product_weight|type|        id_|Weight|               price|dhl_fee|rank|
+--------------+----+-----------+------+--------------------+-------+----+
|             1|   B| 8589934592|     1|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|  17.05|   1|
|             2|   D|25769803776|     2|{A -> 16.78, B ->...|  58.07|   1|
|             4|   A|34359738368|     4|{A -> 20.08, B ->...|  20.08|   1|
|            30|   A|51539607552|    30|{A -> 20.08, B ->...|  20.08|   1|
|           100|   C|60129542144|    40|{A -> 21.08, B ->...|  30.77|   1|
+--------------+----+-----------+------+--------------------+-------+----+
```

Drop the extra columns

```
df = df.select(*requests.columns, 'dhl_fee')
df.show()

+--------------+----+-------+
|product_weight|type|dhl_fee|
+--------------+----+-------+
|             1|   B|  17.05|
|             2|   D|  58.07|
|             4|   A|  20.08|
|            30|   A|  20.08|
|           100|   C|  30.77|
+--------------+----+-------+
```